# What is the SyncState lifetime and max size in Exchange Web Services Manage API?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I'm using the EWS managed API to get the data from some resource calendars.  Every run of my application I get all the items in the calendar, even if I have saved the SyncState used from the last run.  Is there a way to only get the updates?  It seems that the SyncState is tied to the current connection or something.

Secondly, if one can use the SyncState string from a previous run, what is the maximum size of this string?  I would like to store it in a DB and need to know the required record size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can store the SyncState and use it in future requests. Every time you make a call to get the newest items from your calendars you will get a new SyncState object which needs to be stored.

When you create your [SyncFolderItemsType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchangewebservices.syncfolderitemstype%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx) you can add your stored syncstate to it before execution. Look at the link and it should give you an idea.

I am not sure about the maximum size of the SyncState string though.

Thanks

Comment: I too wanted to store the sync token in a datatbase(Amazon Dynamodb) which has a 400KB size limit. I have seen huge SyncState strings, as big as 10 pages of text. I could not come across any documentation about the max size. The entire EWS thing looks very poorly designed.